# MaxTraceFileSize is showing invalid attribute WCF tracing

Tags: xml, wcf, trace

```
    <sources>
        <source name="System.ServiceModel" switchValue="All">
            <listeners>
                <add name="System.ServiceModel.XmlTrace.Listener" />
            </listeners>
        </source>

        <source name="System.Runtime.Serialization" switchValue="All">
            <listeners>
                <add name="System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlTrace.Listener" />
            </listeners>
        </source>
    </sources>

    <sharedListeners>
        <add
            type="MarcW.Tools.Diagnostics.RollingXmlWriterTraceListener, MarcW.Tools"
            name="System.ServiceModel.XmlTrace.Listener"
            traceOutputOptions="None"
            initializeData=".Logs\System.ServiceModel.svclog"
            MaxTraceFileSize="134217728" />
        <add
            type="MarcW.Tools.Diagnostics.RollingXmlWriterTraceListener, MarcW.Tools"
            name="System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlTrace.Listener"
            traceOutputOptions="None"
            initializeData=".Logs\System.Runtime.Serialization.svclog"
            MaxTraceFileSize="134217728" />
    </sharedListeners>
</system.diagnostics>
```

in Config File , When We are using Tracing for WCF **MaxTraceFileSize**  is showing invalid attribute how it can be resolved

Comment: share the Answer

Answer (score 0):

You can try to implement `GetSupportedAttributes` to make .NET read attribute values from config file.
The Attributes collection is not populated from the configuration file until an instance of the listener is fully constructed.

```
protected override string[] GetSupportedAttributes()
{
    return new[] { "MaxTraceFileSize" };
}
```

[Loading Trace Listener Attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11559916/loading-trace-listener-attributes)

local
[image]
example:https://github.com/SebastiaanLubbers/WF_WCF_Samples/tree/master/WCF/Basic/Management/CircularTracing/CS
[image]

Comment: Where it will implemented

Comment: How Can I download Microsoft.ServiceModel.Samples.CircularTracecListener

Comment: How to use GetSupportedAttributes, you can see [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.tracelistener.getsupportedattributes?view=net-6.0).

Comment: [Microsoft.ServiceModel.Samples.CircularTracecListener](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/samples/circular-tracing?redirectedfrom=MSDN) is a custom listener that you can download from the [CircularTracing samples](https://github.com/dotnet/samples/tree/main/framework/wcf).

Comment: This is not working CircularTracing samples

Comment: Is there any easy way to download the Circularlistener or any other way to limit the size of tracing

Comment: You try [this example](https://github.com/SebastiaanLubbers/WF_WCF_Samples/tree/master/WCF/Basic/Management/CircularTracing/CS) and check [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/samples/circular-tracing?redirectedfrom=MSDN).

Comment: <system.diagnostics>
  <sources>
    <source name="System.ServiceModel" switchValue="Information,ActivityTracing" propagateActivity="true">
      <listeners>
        <add name="CircularTraceListener" />
      </listeners>
    </source>
  </sources>
  <sharedListeners>
    <add name="CircularTraceListener" type="Microsoft.ServiceModel.Samples.CircularTraceListener,CircularTraceListener" 
         initializeData="c:\logs\CircularTracing-service.svclog" maxFileSizeKB="100" />
  </sharedListeners>
  <trace autoflush="true" />
</system.diagnostics>

Comment: When I am using this ,error   I am facing Microsoft.ServiceModel.Samples.CircularTraceListener,CircularTraceListener class not find

Comment: I tried the code, no problem, I put the screenshot in the answer, can you post the screenshot of the error message?

Comment: I resolved that error

Comment: FOr circulartracelistener I am creating file type "svclog" like ProLync.PLS.svclog",

Comment: Can I use  TextWriterTraceListener with Circulartracelistener ??

Comment: Trace will show in Text

Comment: I want also my log  in form of c:\Intercepterlog\ProLync.trace.log

Comment: Maybe you can take a look at [this tutorial](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/2680/Writing-custom-NET-trace-listeners).Also see these:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/samples/circular-tracing#circular-buffer-trace-listener and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51171501/how-to-enable-message-and-trace-logging-together-using-circular-tracing-library

Comment: Any suggestion ProLync.PLS.svclog is creating with circulartracing , can I create ProLync.trace.log in textform with circular tracing

Comment: I think you can set `initializeData` in a config file specifying the location and name of the output file. For example: `initializeData="c:\logs\ ProLync.PLS.svclog` "【Note:Trace files are not created without initially creating the log directory. Make sure that the directory C:\logs\ exists, or specify an alternate logging directory in the listener configuration. See the initial setup instructions at the end of this document for more information.】

Comment: Maybe you can provide an answer and mark it as useful so that someone with a similar problem will want to read it.

Comment: Hi , Circular tracing only making 2 files , can we create multiple tracing files  with using same class .

Comment: Any Suggestion?

Comment: Maybe you can look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10965407/17218587).